# Cross domain update hash on opener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have two domain - let's call them newssite.com and app.com.

On newssite.com/myapp I'll insert a iframed version of app.com.

Something like .

When people click on links in that iframe, I want the top main URL in the browser to update, so people can link directly to it, and then I'll load the right url in the iframe.

It should update to something like newssite.com/myapp#!app.com/new/link.html

Is there anyway I can do that? I keep getting cross domain errors ..

Answer (score 0):

Use `<base target="_parent" />` in head of the iframe, or the same attribute in a tags `<a href="doWhatNow" target="_parent">link in iframe</a>`

Comment: That would (just) cause the URL to be loaded in the parent frame, right? It would still be up to the parent to actually handle the request and load the wanted content in the iframe?

Comment: That was not what I was looking for. I don't want to leave the iframe. I want to send a javascript callback from the iframe to the original page ..